# Click event is executed at every click I made apart from active selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup.js

Code that I wrote is as below.

```
<div><a class="skill_1">skill</a></div>
<p id="skill_desc_1">skill description - 1</p>
```

Below JS code is expected to load popup window upon click on .skill_1 element.
however, somehow after first click on .skill_1, whenever I click on elsewhere of website, the click event is executed. as I'm pretty new with JS, I'm really struggling to find out the cause of the issue. perhaps I wrote totally wrong code, can somebody help me out?

I'm using popup.js plugin just for information.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    /* Forcing hidden content to each skill item */
    var options = { content: $('#skill_desc_1')};

    /* popup skill description */
    $('a.skill_1').click(function(){
        $(this).popup(options);
    });
});
```

Comment: You probably want 'class' instead of 'id' for 'skill_desc_1'. This probably won't fix your problem but just a point of order.

Comment: Could be that your `a.skill_1` is filling the entire viewport? That way it would seem that *anywhere* you click it is triggering the popup. Just a thought.

Comment: thanks for comment, @daniel0mullins. when we say a.skill_1 is filling entire viewport, it means the element occupy whole page? I have specified width and height of the box by CSS, do you think it can be viewport issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might try data-rel and data-role as described in the following link instead of popup():

http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/